# Add multiple @groups to valid users

Tags: user-accounts, samba, file-permissions, ubuntu-server

In smb.conf I have the line

```
valid users = @Staff @Directors
```

Is this a valid syntax to add two groups to the valid users line? It does not seem to work right on our xp pro clients.

If not which of the following is the proper way (if any) to make two groups valid users of this network drive?

Which is proper for windows clients?

```
valid users = +Staff +Directors
```

Or do I need to use the &

```
valid users = &Staff &Directors
```

Or some combo of the two?

```
valid users = &+Staff &+Directors
valid users = +&Staff +&Directors
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just add comma ',' if you want multiple valid users. See line that I used below.

```
valid users = @group1, @group2
```

Comment: This is a way quicker solution to my problem... I found the workaround almost a year before you responded.

Answer (score 3):

I wound up adding the users from the most restricted group Directors to the Staff and Interns group as well as their original group. Then I added the users from the Staff group to the Interns group as well as their original group.

The line I used was a simple

```
valid users = @group_name
```

Comment: you should accept your answer as soon as it is possible to mark the question as solved.

Comment: Thanks I clicked it but my browser must have hung up!

Answer (score -1):

On Samba4 with internal dns:

```
valid users = +"cmpc.leg\adm"
```

also works.

Where

```
cmpc.leg=realm
```

and

```
adm=group
```